# php variable passed by jquery and get it for $ _GET to another php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I usually go to the news of the story expanded, passes the variable with a while, as follows:

```
while ($noticias = @mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$sqll = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE id='".$noticias['categoria']."'");
$datos = mysql_fetch_array($sqll);
<div class="leermas">[COLOR="red"]<a href="noticias.php?n='.$noticias['id'].'">[/COLOR]<strong>(Leer m&aacute;s)</strong></a></div>
</div></div>';

}
```

but now I want is to load the content of the page in a div and I usually when I  don't have to pass php variable in this way:
the link for load content

```
<a  class="recursostopwebjqampliada" href="">
```

jQuery code that I have it in an external file called load.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".recursostopwebjqampliada").live("click", function(){ 

$("div#main2").load("topwebjq_ampliada.php?n='.$noticias['id'].'");//AQUI DONDE ESTA LA VARIABLE
     });  
 });
```

and the page that loads the div I get the variable as follows:

```
$id = $_GET['n'];
```

the problem is that jQuery does not read the file php load.js
then how I can fix it

```
load("topwebjq_ampliada.php?n='.$noticias['id'].'"
```

Comment: Define "Does not load". Can you see in Firebug's "Net" tab whether a request is made?

Answer (score 0):

You have to print out the PHP variable inside opening and closing PHP tags like so:

```
$("div#main2").load("topwebjq_ampliada.php?n=<?php echo $noticias['id']; ?>");
```

Now when the page is rendered, you should view the source and see:

```
$("div#main2").load("topwebjq_ampliada.php?n=12345");
```

**Edit:**
Okay, I just noticed that that javascript is in a .js file. You're going to need to move your jQuery code to the file where $noticias['id'] is set so that you can print it out.

Comment: thank you very much but I do not load the content div, it is but when I click on the link does nothing. It works when I put directly n = 50, but not topwebjq_ampliada.php?n=<?php echo $noticias['id']; ?>

Comment: the put the jquery code within the while, he shows me the news but the news is not shown, gives me random, for example I click on the link id is 50 and shows me the ID 46
Listen
Read phonetically